# How to add lights to a Mesh generated by BufferGeometry and drawed as TriangleStrips?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to add lights to a scene where there is a Mesh created by BufferGeometry. The `mesh.drawMode` is `THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode`. I don't know why light is not applying to the mesh.

There is an example bellow:

https://jsbin.com/jofasabeji/edit?js,output

Is there a flag to be activated (like face culling)?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show you code in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your geometry is missing vertex normals.

You can specify the normals yourself, or -- if you find the result acceptable -- you can call:

```
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Alternatively, you can avoid setting vertex normals if you set the material property to flat-shading (and your material supports it):

```
material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
```

Also, you need to set a reasonable intensity for your light:

```
var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
```

three.js r.85

Comment: Thanks! How can I specify the normals by myself? Can you point out any documentation, reference or example?